# C++: Container of different types

Tags: c++, templates, containers, function-pointers

I have some functions (simple for this example) with different paramaters:

```
int addNums(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int squareNum(int a) {
    return a * a;
}
```

I have a template class `action` which has a function pointer which will eventually point to either of the above functions:

```
template<class T>
class action {
public:
    std::string descriptionOfAction;
    T functionPtr;
};
```

I have a class `user` which should have some form of a container of `action`s:

```
class user {
public:
    std::string name;

    //container of actions
};
```

In `main`, I defined and initialized two `action`s to correspond with the first two functions listed above:

```
action<int(*)(int, int)> addAction;
addAction.descriptionOfAction = "Add two numbers together";
addAction.functionPtr = addNums;

action<int(*)(int)> squareAction;
squareAction.descriptionOfAction = "Square a number";
squareAction.functionPtr = squareNum;
```

Now I want to insert both of these `action`s into a `user`s container of `action`s:

```
user aUser;
aUser.name = "User's Name";
//insert "addAction" and "squareAction" to user's container of actions
```

Because of the templating, these `action`s are not the same types. Is there an existing type of container to hold these? If not, is there a way to do something similar without templates? Ideally, when a `user` "uses" one of the `action`s in their container, the `action` should be erased.

Comment: How do you expect to use these functions when they have different argument lists?  Assuming you could do what you want, how would the user know which argument list to use?

Comment: What about `std::variant` ? If you can use C++17.

Comment: On a more primitive approach, a templated tagged union..

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that functions have different *arity* (i.e., the number of arguments).

It's not much of a problem to put your functions into some container. You can always put your functions into an `std::vector<void*>` (the compiler does not care), but then... what? What's the plan?

You will also need to add function arity to the same container, so it transforms to `std::vector<std::pair<void*, unsigned int>>` (function pointer + arity). This automatically complicates your action adding, since you will obviously won't want to specify the arity by hand, and you will want to automate this in order to avoid any human error. This *will* involve templates. Moreover, you will need to manually inspect the arities and pass the appropriate number of parameters. This will be error prone, too.

The most simple approach would be to define some

```
struct my_function_interface {
    virtual int operator()(<all your parameters here>) = 0;
};
```

And then define your actions in term of that interface. This is a classic OOP solution, which abstracts away all your problems. Moreover, it will most likely be more performant, since all your checks and special function invocations won't come for free. Here, you will have a single virtual function call.

Comment: Thanks for your response and for introducing me to arity. I feel a little slighted that I've had 3 semesters of C++ classes and I've never heard of this until now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store pointers to functions as `void*`. A pointer-to-function is not the same as a pointer-to-variable.

If you want to store multiple types in one variable, use `std::variant` if you can use C++17, otherwise use a `union` if you can't.

Comment: There is _absolutely_ no difference between pointers. A pointer is a pointer. Be it to a function, to a variable or to whatever else you want in your computer's memory. What matters is what you do with that pointer.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#cant-cvt-memfnptr-to-voidptr